# Line up two blocks and avoid they stand on one another

Tags: html, css

I have been trying for a while now to make those two blocks stand aside one another on the same line in vain!

Can you help me enlight this out

here http://jsfiddle.net/9UxZ8/2/

```
<div class="bookinfo">
<h2 id="bleu">Hello,how are you</h2>
<h3 id="auteur">John Jogn</h3>
<h4 id="coll">Kings and Queens</h4>
</div><div class="chapter">
<div id="gros"><h3 >I truly believe that you are a cleaver person, but please remain quiet.</h3></div></div>


div#gros
{
color:red;
width:350px;
font-size:30px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
}

div.bookinfo {
vertical-align:top;
display: inline-block;
width: 300px;
vertical-align:top;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your markup there are two parent div which are `.bookInfo` and `.chapter`. So I am assuming you want to put them aside one another. So for that

Add `display:inline-block` to `.chapter`

```
.chapter
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9UxZ8/4/)

Answer (score 0):

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9UxZ8/3/)

While you had the right idea in theory (except the duplicate `vertical-align:top`), you're missing the important fact that the elements to be put side-by-side are `.bookinfo` and `.chapter`, NOT `.bookinfo` and `#gros`.

Comment: Actually, .chapter is a div that i've shorten to post it here, it contains other divs in the real file, so what you mean is that, one cannot expect to put two divs aside, if the second div is part of another div?